# Link an entity that isn't the "Primary" entity

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I've been asked to create a report on some data from CRM using FetchXML. I have never used this language before so I think this may be an easy question.

I have the following code:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="bie_backbonus" enableprefiltering="1">
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractno" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonusnoteforletter" />
    <attribute name="bie_offdate" />
    <attribute name="bie_ondate" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractversion" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractname" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontactname" />
    <attribute name="bie_legacybackbonuscode" />
    <attribute name="owneridname" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
<link-entity name="bie_backbonusproductgroup" from="bie_backbonuscontractno" to="bie_backbonusid" alias="pg" link-type="outer">
    <attribute name="bie_tier2percent" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier2value" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier3percent" />
    <attribute name="bie_productsubtype" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier1value" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier3value" />
    <attribute name="bie_producttype" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier1percent" />
 </link-entity>
<link-entity name="bie_producttype" from="bie_name" to="bie_producttype" alias="p" link-type="outer">
    <attribute name="bie_producttypenl" />
</link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I have tried to link three entities above but the bie_producttype entity needs to link to the bie_backbonusproductgroup entity not bie_backbonus which I think it is. Is there a function or way to link to other entities than the "Primary" one?

I have also tried using http://www.sql2fetchxml.com/ but this produced code that my report couldn't read.

I am a SQL Developer and the code would be this if written in SQL:

```
SELECT  b.bie_backbonuscontractno
   ,b.bie_backbonusnoteforletter 
   ,b.bie_offdate
   ,b.bie_ondate
   ,b.bie_backbonuscontractversion
   ,b.bie_backbonuscontractname
   ,b.bie_backbonuscontactname
   ,b.bie_legacybackbonuscode
   ,b.owneridname
   ,b.createdon
   ,pg.bie_tier2percent
   ,pg.bie_tier2value
   ,pg.bie_tier3percent
   ,pg.bie_productsubtype
   ,pg.bie_tier1value
   ,pg.bie_tier3value
   ,pg.bie_producttype
   ,pg.bie_tier1percent
   ,p.bie_producttypenl
FROM bie_backbonus b
JOIN bie_backbonusproductgroup pg ON pg.bie_backbonuscontractno =    b.bie_backbonusid
JOIN bie_producttype p ON p.bie_name = pg.bie_producttype
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As you dive deeper into FetchXML, please note that you can export the FetchXML from Advanced Find queries. And, the [FetchXML Builder](https://fxb.xrmtoolbox.com/) tool in the [XrmToolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) is handy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to nest `link-entity` in FetchXML. When looking at your query above it appears that you have both `link-entity` on the outermost level, which explains why it joins with `bie_backbonus` instead of `bie_backbonusproductgroup` as you expect.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="bie_backbonus" enableprefiltering="1">
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractno" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonusnoteforletter" />
    <attribute name="bie_offdate" />
    <attribute name="bie_ondate" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractversion" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontractname" />
    <attribute name="bie_backbonuscontactname" />
    <attribute name="bie_legacybackbonuscode" />
    <attribute name="owneridname" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
<link-entity name="bie_backbonusproductgroup" from="bie_backbonuscontractno" to="bie_backbonusid" alias="pg" link-type="outer">
    <attribute name="bie_tier2percent" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier2value" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier3percent" />
    <attribute name="bie_productsubtype" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier1value" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier3value" />
    <attribute name="bie_producttype" />
    <attribute name="bie_tier1percent" />
    <!-- ↓ This has been moved inwards -->
    <link-entity name="bie_producttype" from="bie_name" to="bie_producttype" alias="p" link-type="outer">
        <attribute name="bie_producttypenl" />
    </link-entity>
    <!-- ↑ This has been moved inwards -->
 </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```